# FtpStreamingMessageSource - retry on failure

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I have configured spring integration with this beans:

```
private static final Pattern FILE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("<pattern>");

@Bean
public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory(){
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    factory.setPort(21);
    factory.setUsername("root");
    factory.setPassword("123456");
    factory.setClientMode(FTPClient.PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentMetadataStore metadataStore(){
    PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore  store = new PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore();
    store.setFileName("ftpStore.properties");
    return store;
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource selectDataSource(){
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://10.10.10.10:33306/csv");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("123456");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(selectDataSource());
}

@Bean
public TransactionSynchronizationFactory synchronizationFactory(){
    return new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(new TransactionSynchronizationProcessor() {
        @Override
        public void processBeforeCommit(IntegrationResourceHolder integrationResourceHolder) {
            int x = 22; //???
        }

        @Override
        public void processAfterCommit(IntegrationResourceHolder integrationResourceHolder) {
            int x = 22; //???
        }

        @Override
        public void processAfterRollback(IntegrationResourceHolder integrationResourceHolder) {
            int x = 22; //???
        }
    });
}

@Bean
public PollerMetadata pollerMetadata(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager){
    PeriodicTrigger trigger = new PeriodicTrigger(5000);
    trigger.setFixedRate(true);

    MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource source = new MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource();
    source.setTransactionAttribute(new DefaultTransactionAttribute());
    TransactionInterceptor interceptor = new TransactionInterceptor(transactionManager, source);

    PollerMetadata metadata = new PollerMetadata();
    metadata.setTrigger(trigger);
    metadata.setTransactionSynchronizationFactory(synchronizationFactory());
    metadata.setAdviceChain(Collections.singletonList(interceptor));
    return metadata;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpChannel", poller = @Poller("pollerMetadata"))
public MessageSource<InputStream> ftpMessageSource(){
    FtpStreamingMessageSource source = new FtpStreamingMessageSource(new FtpRemoteFileTemplate(ftpSessionFactory()));
    source.setRemoteDirectory("ftp/folder");
    source.setFilter(new CompositeFileListFilter<>(Arrays.asList(
            new FtpRegexPatternFileListFilter(FILE_PATTERN),
            acceptOnceFileListFilter()
    )));
    return source;
}

@Bean
public FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter acceptOnceFileListFilter(){
    FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter filter = new FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(), "remote");
    filter.setFlushOnUpdate(true);
    return filter;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "newChannel")
public MessageHandler handler(){
    return new MessageHandler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            System.out.println(message.getPayload());
            throw new MessagingException("error");
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel ftpChannel(){
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel newChannel(){
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel strChannel(){
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel = "ftpChannel", outputChannel = "strChannel")
public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer transformer2(){
    return new StreamTransformer("UTF-8");
}

@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel = "strChannel", outputChannel = "newChannel")
public UnmarshallingTransformer transformer(){
    UnmarshallingTransformer transformer = new UnmarshallingTransformer(unmarshaller());
    return transformer;
}

@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller unmarshaller(){
    Jaxb2Marshaller unmarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    unmarshaller.setContextPath("com.generated.xsd");
    return unmarshaller;
}
```

My problem is that on `throw new MessagingException("error");`, all ftp files are saved to `ftpStore.properties` and on next reload (eg. if JVM fails), this files will not be processed ever again. How can I make sure that transaction is in place (that is if there is no exception file is saved to `ftpStore.properties` and otherwise not)? Is there some tutorial to follow in order to have failure-proof download of files from FTP Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `ResettableFileListFilter` abstraction on the matter do deal with.

And in fact your `FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` is a such one:

> If, after synchronizing the files, an error occurs on the downstream flow processing a file, there is no automatic rollback of the filter so the failed file will not be reprocessed by default.
>
> If you wish to reprocess such files after a failure, you can use configuration similar to the following to facilitate the removal of the failed file from the filter. This will work for any `ResettableFileListFilter`.

The XML config sample is like this:

```
<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
    <int:after-rollback expression="@acceptOnceFilter.remove(payload)" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>
```

So, what you need is to adjust your `synchronizationFactory` with an appropriate `DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory` and `ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor`, respectively.

See [Recovering from Failures](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#_recovering_from_failures).

Comment: I'm just trying to do it this way, but it seems I need FTPFile object inside that Spel `processor.setAfterRollbackExpression(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("@acceptOnceFileListFilter.remove(headers.get('file_remoteFile'))"));` since this is not working. Also, in this way, file is written immediattely, and only deleted after rollback. Is there a way that I write to `metadataStore` file only after commit is OK? This way if JVM fails before commit, files will still be written and saved in `metadataStore`!

Comment: Well, indeed you need `FTPFile`. We have introduced the `FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE_INFO` since `5.0`: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4233. The TX sync idea might have sense, indeed. But for that purpose the `metadataStore` must be transactional resource, e.g. JDBC. But we don't have that one yet...

Comment: I just found this page, which may have some kind of solution http://javaday.org.ua/spring-integration-add-failover-support-to-ftp-inbound-channel/

Comment: Well, that is good write up, but that still doesn't provide the TX semantics. They still store some data into the `medataStore` and not during commit, but as regular `accept()`... Feel free to raise a JIRA on the matter and let's together come up with the out-of-the-box solution!

Comment: Yes, but I think they flag it first as IN_PROGRESS, then only on commit put state to DONE. Worst case is that they process the same file more than once I think.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand that part, too... Anyway that is already different story